# What value of resistance to put between the output of a 74hc595 and the LEDs?

Tags: led, shift-register

I'm going to start a project to make an array of LEDs using the shift registers **74HC595**, I've seen many tutorials and it's not really difficult using the Arduino plataform.

The situation is as follows: in the tutorials they put a resistance between the outputs of the **74HC595** (*Qx*) and the **LEDs** , but in each tutorial the resistance varies (*between **200** and **575** Ohms*).

Then the question would be: if feed with **5V** to **74HC595** (the same power as the Arduino) and the resistance that I put between its **outputs (Qx)** and the **LEDs** is lower (let's say **200 Ohms**), the LEDs will light brighter than if I do it with resistors with higher values (let's say **500 Ohms**)?

Comment: What does the 74HC595 datasheet say about maximum current per output and maximum current for the entire IC? The Texas Instruments datasheet uses 560 ohms per LED on the Typical Application page.

Comment: @VE7JRO, the OP is asking, using a lot of words, if a 200 ohm series resistor will produce brighter LED output when compared to a 500 ohm series resistor.

Comment: I know the Ohm´s law, I just asking for experience, I Live in Cuba and is very dificult to me order pieces (when I buy them I have to wait almost 4 month to get them); so, when I order I try to order "things" that I would know that will work, I ask for this reason. Sorry

Comment: They say 25mA per output.

Comment: no need to apologize .... then you should be asking about what @VE7JRO mentioned in the above comment .... can the 74HC595 handle the load when all the LEDs are on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that a lower resistance would offer higher brightness. The more current through the LED, the brighter it will be. The current is calculated by dividing the voltage across the resistor by resistance value. The voltage across the resistor would be your 5V - the voltage drop across the LED. this often varies by color. A RED LED might have a 1.2V drop, and GREEN or BLUE would be higher. So to get the same relative brightness in different color LEDS, you will often see a lower resistance used, to get the same current.

Lets say you have a 20mA Red LED, with a 1.2V drop. So (5 - 1.2)/.020 = 190 ohms. If the LED required 10mA, that would be 380 ohms.

Now you DO need to look at the data sheet for the chip driving the LED, and make sure it is up to the task. Can a pin source or sink 10mA? 20mA?